# Go vendor major update modules

Tags: go, vendor

In my project there is third party modules that used entire project. It's importing like below

```
import github.com/username/my-package/v4
```

This modules is stored in vendor directory like below;

```
vendor
   - >github.com
         - >username
               - >my-package
                     - >v4
                        . 
                        .
```

There is new version of this package with v5 version instead of v4. I should major update.

```
import github.com/username/my-package/v5
```

How can i update this major update? I install the latest version but when I go mod vendor nothing happened. New version is not installed the vendor directory and I can't use it.
By the way is there a way that I can use both v4 and v5 version cuz i don't want to update all import paths but I'm okay if I have to migrate all paths.

Thank you folks,

Comment: What is the error? Have you run `go get` for the new package, or `go mod tidy`?

Comment: 1) Modify the `require` directive for this module in your `go.mod` to have the new version. 2) Run `go mod vendor`. 3) Modify the import paths in your code to use the new version.